# Is Linux file system layer(not the VFS) aware of page cache

Tags: linux, filesystems, vfs, page-caching

In Linux file system i understand Page cache is between VFS and the file system.  Want to know, at any point of time whether the file system will be aware of the pages (of a file) that are in the page cache or only VFS layer only will have this info?

Which layer implements page cache logic (VFS or FS )? Which part of the linux kernal code to start with to understand this?

Is page cache implementation is differet for different file system (like it is different for single node file systems like ext4 and for distributed file system like GFS2)?

| VFS | --> | Page cache | --> | file system eg: ext4  |